# iScroll hide/show scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

I am trying to implement a hover feature on my iScroll div, where I am able to show/hide the scrollbar. I'd like to have the user hover over the div and have the scrollbar appear and once the user moves the mouse off the container the scrollbar disappears.

I've been looking into this to see if its possible but havent had much luck trying to find a solution. I've found that iScroll has a hideScrollbar parameter that I can be set when initializing the new iScroll object but not entirely sure how to dynamically set the parameter based on the users interaction with the scroll container.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The below code will give what you want. :) (Tested Desktop & Android & iOS);

```
hideScrollbar: !isIDevice || isIDevice || isAndroid,
fadeScrollbar: !isIDevice || isIDevice && has3d,
```

This is the same line with vletech said before 112-113.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find the parameter `hideScrollbar` as you mentioned above, but an easy way around this would be to add your own fade animation on it.

E.g.

```
$('#DivToHover').hover(
   function(){
      $('#ScrollBarDiv').fadeIn("fast");
   },
   function(){
      $('#ScrollBarDiv').fadeOut("fast");
   }
);
```

But this might cause some problems if you're expecting this to be viewable on mobile devices.

**EDIT**

Change line 35 to.

`isIDevice = (/iphone|ipad|Mozilla/gi).test(navigator.appVersion),`

**EDIT 2**
Thinking about this again a better way would be to leave line 35 as it is `(/iphone|ipad/gi)`. But change lines 112 & 133 to ...

```
hideScrollbar: isIDevice && !isIDevice,
fadeScrollbar: isIDevice && !isIDevice && has3d,
```

Comment: if you go here https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll.js and view line 112 you can see the parameter there. I will give your solution a try to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: ahh ok I didn't see that before... so Idevice is referencing iPhones and iPads (`(/iphone|ipad/gi).test(navigator.appVersion)`) so the easiest thing to do is to reference all other browsers as well, please see my edit for an alternative solution.

Comment: I think you might need more that just Mozilla but I'm finding it hard to track down the other appVersion names.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a second edit... please have a look....PS don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped.